# When I try to log in with my OpenID, I see a weird user name

Tags: support

I try to log in to Server Fault with my OpenID, but it gives me this weird username: [user24929](https://serverfault.com/users/24929).

Also, earlier, I asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/112085/is-buying-a-poweredge-2970-a-bad-idea) but I was logged out so just entered [my name and email](https://serverfault.com/users/34571/yan-bellavance) and now I cannot edit this question anymore.  Can that question be transferred to my real account?

Comment: @yan: I put a link to the ServerFault user I think you are. I could be wrong, though, so please let me know if I am and I will gladly remove it. (Or you can by clicking the "edit" link.)

Comment: Everyone else: This is @yan's correct (note matching gravatar) SF profile: http://serverfault.com/users/34571/yan-bellavance

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to e-mail [team@stackoverflow.com](http://mailto:team@stackoverflow.com) and have them merge the two accounts. The trick will be making sure that the OpenID you're using to sign in currently is the one which the other account gets merged into.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you cleared your cookies since you asked that question.

As long as your cookies are in place, use the "register" link at the top of the page to roll a unregistered (cookie-based) account into a registered (openid-based) account.